How to Merge Rows values into a Column on a prior Row?
In power query, I'm attempting to create a formula that creates a new column called "Options" to contain the following combined row information together ignoring null values.
Example Table where rows that are filled in with yellow are the row values I want to have combined into prior row where column "#" doesn't contain a null value:

Desired Result, wish to have row values combined and delimited by a comma:


You'll receive more help if you post your data as text. Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?

I created the solution for you:

It utilizes this formula:
[G2] =LET(
  c,COLUMNS(Table1),at_l,INDEX(Table1,0,c),n,ROWS(Table1),
  af,FILTER(HSTACK(Table1,SEQUENCE(n)),Table1[Product]<>"null"),
  af_l,INDEX(af,0,c+1),aw,DROP(VSTACK(af_l,n+1),1),
  HSTACK(
    TAKE(af,,c),
    MAP(af_l,aw,LAMBDA(i,j,TEXTJOIN(", ",FALSE,DROP(TAKE(at_l,j-1),i))))
  )
)

For anybody who is interesting in the algorithm:

Add numeration to the source table.
Filter the table by product only. The resulting array will be used as the part of the whole result.
Create the vertical vector from the numeration column shifted up one row then add at the end the total rows plus 1. These two columns define start and end rows of the source table for each product entry.
For each product, join Item Names from start row to the end row exclusively and attach this column to the result.


One more formula:
=HSTACK(
  FILTER(Table1[#All],Table1[[#All],['#]]<>"null"),
  TOCOL(TEXTSPLIT(", "&TEXTJOIN(", ",FALSE,IF(Table1['#]="null",Table1[Item Name],"")),", , "))
)


=LET(x,SCAN(,Table1['#],LAMBDA(a,b,IF(b="null",a,b))),
     MAP(UNIQUE(x),LAMBDA(y,ARRAYTOTEXT(FILTER(Table1[Item Name],x=y)))))

SCAN repeats the previous values in # in case null next we use MAP to loop through the unique values of that array and filter out the Item Name values where the value of the scan-array (x) equals the unique value of x which is being looped. The filter result is wrapped in ARRAYTOTEXT.
Edit after Rotabor's comment:
=LET(x,SCAN(,Table1['#],LAMBDA(a,b,IF(b="null",a,b))),u,UNIQUE(x),MAKEARRAY(ROWS(u),6,LAMBDA(a,b,IF(b<6,XLOOKUP(INDEX(u,a),Table1['#],CHOOSECOLS(Table1,b)),ARRAYTOTEXT(DROP(FILTER(+Table1[Item Name],x=INDEX(u,a)),1))))))
And avoiding makearray (Rotabor):
=LET(x,SCAN(,Table1['#],LAMBDA(a,b,IF(b="null",a,b))),HSTACK(FILTER(Table1,Table1[Product]<>"null"),MAP(UNIQUE(x),LAMBDA(y,ARRAYTOTEXT(DROP(FILTER(Table1[Item Name],x=y),1))))))

In Power Query i loaded the table "Tabelle1" and duplicated it. The name for the first query is "Tabelle1". I've named the second (duplicated) query "Query1".
The code for the first query ("Tabelle1") is this:
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Tabelle1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"#", Int64.Type}, {"QTY", Int64.Type}, {"Product", type text}, {"Option", type text}, {"Item Name", type text}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Product1", each if [Option] = null then [Product] else null),
    #"Filled Down" = Table.FillDown(#"Added Custom",{"Product1", "#", "QTY"}),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Filled Down", each ([Option] <> null)),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{"Product", "Option"}),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Removed Columns",{{"Product1", "Product"}}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Renamed Columns", {"#", "QTY", "Product"}, {{"Count", each _, type table}}),
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Userdefined", each Text.Combine([Count][Item Name],", ")),
    #"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom1",{"Count"}),
    #"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Removed Columns1",{"#", "QTY", "Product"},Query1,{"#", "QTY", "Product"},"ItemNames (2)",JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    #"Expanded {0}" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "ItemNames (2)", {"Option", "Item Name"}, {"Option", "Item Name"}),
    #"Reordered Columns1" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Expanded {0}",{"#", "QTY", "Product", "Option", "Item Name", "Userdefined"}),
    #"Renamed Columns1" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Reordered Columns1",{{"Userdefined", "Product2"}})
in
    #"Renamed Columns1"

This is the code for the second query ("Query1"):
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Tabelle1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"#", Int64.Type}, {"QTY", Int64.Type}, {"Product", type text}, {"Option", type text}, {"Item Name", type text}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Product1", each if [Option] = null then [Product] else null),
    #"Filled Down" = Table.FillDown(#"Added Custom",{"Product1", "#", "QTY"}),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Filled Down", each ([Option] = null))
in
    #"Filtered Rows"



Using formula:

Get row indices for from/to based on "null" in "#" col
Select rows from row indices
Combine sorted unique item names

=LET(
    indices, SEQUENCE(ROWS(Table1)),
    from, TOCOL(IF(Table1['#] <> "null", indices, NA()), 2),
    to, DROP(IF(TAKE(from, -1) <> MAX(indices), VSTACK(from, MAX(indices) + 1), from), 1),
    items_to_list, LAMBDA(from, to,
        IFNA(
            ARRAYTOTEXT(
                SORT(UNIQUE(INDEX(Table1[Item Name], SEQUENCE(to - from - 1, , from + 1))))
            ),
            ""
        )
    ),
    option2, MAP(from, to, items_to_list),
    hash_details, VSTACK(Table1[#Headers], CHOOSEROWS(Table1, from)),
    HSTACK(hash_details, VSTACK("Options2", option2))
)



Power Query
Using almost similar logic as above,
let

  SourceExcel = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name = "Table1"]}[Content],
  addedIndex = Table.AddIndexColumn(SourceExcel, "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
  addedFromCol = Table.TransformColumnTypes(
    Table.AddColumn(addedIndex, "From", each if [#"#"] <> "null" then [Index] else null),
    {{"From", Int64.Type}}
  ),

  Source = addedFromCol,
  from = Table.SelectRows(Source, each [From] <> null),
  lastFrom = Table.Last(Source)[Index]
    + (if Table.Last(from)[From] <> Table.Last(Source)[Index] then 1 else 0),
  to = List.RemoveFirstN(List.Combine({from[From], {lastFrom}}), 1),
  count = List.Transform(List.Zip({to, from[From]}), each _{0} - _{1} - 1),

  option2 = List.Transform(
    List.Zip({from[From], count}),
    each Text.Combine(List.Sort(List.Distinct(List.Range(Source[Item Name], _{0} + 1, _{1}))), ", ")
  ),

  cols = Table.ToColumns(from) & {option2},
  headers = Table.ColumnNames(from) & {"Option2"},
  result = Table.FromColumns(cols, headers),
  removedTempCols = Table.RemoveColumns(result, {"Index", "From"})
  
in
  removedTempCols


